# hacer que check box coloque IsNotEnable al Seleccionarse

Tags: c#, mvvm, silverlight

En mi código tengo la opción de que al seleccionar un check box ciertos controles se coloquen habilitados como lo indico en este código en el archivos XAML:

```
<TextBox Grid.Row="8" Grid.Column="1" Name="DiasAtraso" HorizontalAlignment="Left"
                 IsEnabled="{Binding ElementName=cbAgregarManual, Path=IsChecked }" 
                 VerticalAlignment="Center" Margin="10,1,0,1" Height="26" Width="100" 

             StringFormat=\{0\}}" TextAlignment="Right" MaxLength="2" IsReadOnly="False" />
```

el combobox se llama: cbAgregarManual y con *Path=IsChecked* habilita

pero resultó que se necesita que cuando se seleccione NO los habilite; Estoy trabajando con patrón MVVM y SILVERLIGHT 5 se que se puede realizar algo como se muestra en esto otro [hilo](https://stackoverflow.com/a/18120145/4668184) pero NO deseo hacerlo con este patrón.

Existe una forma Donde solo se pueda realizar en la vista?

Comment: Si. Pero necesitas un conversor de valores para que invierta el booleano (entiendo que te refieres a `IsChecked`)

Comment: @Pikoh entonces necesariamente se tiene que crear una propiedad en el viewmodel? si es al isChecked..

Comment: No he dicho una propiedad. He dicho un conversor de valor (ValueConverter) :) Echa un vistazo a [esta respuesta](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1039681/579895)

Comment: @Pikoh puedes colocar código de ejemplo.. me quedaria mas facil entenderte con código

Comment: Mira el enlace que acabo de poner en mi anterior comentario :)

Comment: @Pikoh eso resulta más "laborioso" que hacer el bindeo a el IsChecked a una propiedad  viewmodel ;)

Comment: Bueno, tu pregunta era si existía la posibilidad, y existir existe. En cuanto a si es mas "laborioso", todo depende. Debes tener en cuenta que una vez tienes el conversor hecho, puedes usarlo para cualquier propiedad que necesites invertir, y si lo agregas en una dll, puedes usarlo en otros proyectos.